# recursive function to loop through object and nested object with javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, object, recursion, nested-loops

to update my question I would like to be able to access each value on objects and nested objects but I I don't know how to do this. I tried first with a foreach loop and a for loop but I didn't know how to get "comment" for example

```
data.forEach((element) => {
    const name = element.restaurantName;
    const address = element.address;
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        const comment = element.ratings[i].comment;
    }
    init_resto(name, address, comment);
});

var list_group = document.getElementById('list-group'); 

function init_resto(name, address, comment) {
    var liElt = document.createElement('li');
    liElt.innerHTML = 
    "<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + name + "</li>" +  
    "<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + address + "</li>" +
    "<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + comment + "</li>";  
    list_group.appendChild(liElt);
}
```

My expected output :

```
"branco"
"39 Rue des Petites Écuries, 75010 Paris"
"Un excellent restaurant, j'y reviendrai ! Par contre il vaut mieux aimer la viande."
Tout simplement mon restaurant préféré !

"Babalou"
"address":"4 Rue Lamarck, 75018 Paris"
"Une minuscule pizzeria délicieuse cachéejuste à côté du Sacré choeur !"
...
```

Here is my datas:

```
[
    {
       "restaurantName":"Bronco",
       "address":"39 Rue des Petites Écuries, 75010 Paris",
       "lat":48.8737815,
       "long":2.3501649,
       "ratings":[
          {
             "stars":4,
             "comment":"Un excellent restaurant, j'y reviendrai !Par contre il vaut mieux aimer la viande."
          },
          {
             "stars":5,
             "comment":"Tout simplement mon restaurant préféré !"
          }
       ]
    },
    {
       "restaurantName":"Babalou",
       "address":"4 Rue Lamarck, 75018 Paris",
       "lat":48.8865035,
       "long":2.3442197,
       "ratings":[
          {
             "stars":5,
             "comment":"Une minuscule pizzeria délicieuse cachéejuste à côté du Sacré choeur !"
          },
          {
             "stars":3,
             "comment":"J'ai trouvé ça correct, sans plus"
          }
       ]
    }
 ]
```

then I tried with a recursive function which can be a better way but I don't know how to get all values without overriding these values :

```
function recurse(obj) {
    let value= "";
    for (let property in obj) { 
        value = obj[property];

        if(typeof obj[property] == "object" && obj[property] !== null) { 
            value = recurse(obj[property]);  
        }

    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: With a function you can only return one value. To return multiple values, use a generator function. Alternatively pass in a function, and call it for every value.

Comment: You are only returning one value because in your for loop, you set value, and then override it each time. It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish with your recursion, and that info is necessary for a fix.

Comment: Sorry if it's unclear, I would like to iterate on each value to access them, like for example ```  data.forEach((element) => {
     const name = element.restaurantName;
     const address = element.address; });``` but the problem with this it's I cannot access to nested objects without doing another loop like ``` for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     const comment = element.ratings[i].comment; ``` and it gives me complications after that. I have also seen that It was maybe possible doing that recursivly, and I would like to understand other possibilities

Comment: So you want your function not to return anything, but simply console.logging all properties (including nested ones)? In other words - what exactly do you mean by "access them"?

Comment: Console.log was just an example, I would like to write into a list all of the data nested or not in my data file

Comment: Still not sure what you want to do - you really need to be more specific in order for us to help you. You mean you want a flat list of all props, e.g. `["Bronco", "39 Rue des Petites Écuries, 75010 Paris", 48.8737815, 2.3501649, ....]`? The best thing to do is to edit your question and add the expected output there..

Comment: I'm afraid this is still unclear after the update.  Do you want to make four calls to `init_resto`, one for each comment for each restaurant?  Or do you want to make two calls to it, one for each restaurant?  And if the latter, do you want to send it all nested comments, or find a way to choose one of them?  Also, why does your output include the `address` key in one but not the other?

Answer (score 2):

Comments have explained why your code is returning only a single value.

It's pretty hard to tell for sure what you're looking to do.  If what you want is just to collect the leaf values of your object tree, then this simple recursion should do it:

```js
const getValues = (obj) => 
  Object (obj) === obj
    ? Object .values (obj) .flatMap (getValues)
    : obj

const input = [{restaurantName: "Bronco", address: "39 Rue des Petites Écuries, 75010 Paris", lat: 48.8737815, long: 2.3501649, ratings: [{stars: 4, comment: "Un excellent restaurant, j'y reviendrai !Par contre il vaut mieux aimer la viande."}, {stars: 5, comment: "Tout simplement mon restaurant préféré !"}]}, {restaurantName: "Babalou", address: "4 Rue Lamarck, 75018 Paris", lat: 48.8865035, long: 2.3442197, ratings: [{stars: 5, comment: "Une minuscule pizzeria délicieuse cachéejuste à côté du Sacré choeur !"}, {stars: 3, comment: "J'ai trouvé ça correct, sans plus"}]}]

console .log (input .map (getValues))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

(I find `Object (obj) === obj` a cleaner typecheck than doing `typeof`.)

But if that is not your expected output, please edit the question to include the expected output.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but It is not what I'm looking for exactly, I've eddited my question, I don't know if now it's clear

Comment: I'm afraid it's still unclear.  I commented more on the question itself.